# Most efficient way to search and replace in a multidimensional array

Tags: java, algorithm, search, multidimensional-array, replace

What is the best way (in terms of big-O) to search for and replace an element in a multidimensional unsorted array, retaining the structure and not transforming it into another data structure?

I'm preferably looking for a solution in Java without using any language specific libraries.

Comment: Wouldn't it be O(n) to just traverse through each item and check if it matches the search term and then modify that index? (This question is more towards other SO users)

Comment: @MikeKoch: Depends on what `n` is. If you mean the total size of the matrix, then yes.

Comment: Depending on what is meant with "replace" you could perform the modifications while traversing the matrix. This way it would stay at ``O(n)``

Comment: Typically anything linear is `O(n)`. If you traverse a 10-element array, and you make 10 comparisons, it's `O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

If you have an unsorted collection/array, you won't do better than O(n) reliably because you cannot predict the proceeding elements, meaning you will have to traverse each one.

This is why collections that remain sorted exist.

Comment: @YonatanN true, but if I remember correctly it isn't always correct (note: reliably)

Comment: @Rogue It isn't (though you can make incorrect answers arbitrarily unlikely by running it several times). But since we're already here: Other models of computation permit even more magic, such as arbitrary amounts of work in constant time. Admittedly, those are far less likely to be physically realizable.